# Sum results of subselects union

Tags: sql, ms-access

hey i am trying to sum the results of two different result sets after combining then in a unio.  the aim is to get the difference difference of the counts for each description.

using the below i get an error in union statement from MS ACCESS.
or if i add an extra parenthis after the from i get error in join.

any ideas????

```
select description, sum(CP)

from

(select  description, count(description)
*-1 AS CP
from status
where date_loaded between #1/1/2014# and #2/1/2014#
group by description) 
Union all
(select  description, count(description) AS CP
from status
where date_loaded between #1/1/2014# and #3/1/2014#
group by description)
```

group by description

Comment: What is the problem? Unexpected result? An error?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do a `union` in a subquery (among the many problems with MS Access).  Fortunately, you can do what you want with conditional aggregation:

```
select description,
       count(*) - sum(iif(date_loaded between #1/1/2014# and #2/1/2014#, 1, 0)) as diff
from status
where date_loaded between #1/1/2014# and #3/1/2014#
group by description;
```

I think the following also does what you want:

```
select description,
       sum(iif(date_loaded between #2/2/2014# and #3/1/2014#, 1, 0)) as newest
from status
where date_loaded between #1/1/2014# and #3/1/2014#
group by description;
```